# How to draw a tree using Gtkmm?

Tags: gtkmm

I want to draw a tree, to visualize this abstract data structure.

Are there any existing libraries for me to do this? I don't want to manually write Cairo code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GooCanvas](http://live.gnome.org/GooCanvas) worked for me to draw the trees in [my application](http://gnome-inform7.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gnome-inform7/branches/gtk2-12-branch/). It also has C++ bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at something I asked a year ago…

Graphviz was the path I took then. Only an approximation but enough for an uninteresting homework.